# textract Api it's possible to specify the area where to retrieve the text

Tags: amazon-textract

since i have to analyze a series of documents with the same format, but it does not always recover a particular field, it is possibile to recover text by specifying the area from which to withdraw it,
exploiting for example the posistion?

"Width": 0.03215303644537926,
"Height": 0.005642734467983246,
"Left": 0.05062320828437805,
"Top": 0.7153081297874451

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can specify the area to recover text from.

As a possible solution: you could use  [Textract Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Query.html) to attempt to recover the particular field that is not being picked up with your initial attempts and see if that is successful.